# ffmpeg: -ss and -t on input doesn't change output duration

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to encode a 1-minute portion from a 2 hours video file. I use `-ss` to seek to the point I want, use `-t` to specify the duration, both are used as input option. I then play the output with `mpv` and it reports that the video duration is still 2h, although it does terminate after 1 minute after successfully played through the encoded sequence. `ffprobe` still reports that the video is 1 minute in length. Do I have to worry about this behavior?

`ffmpeg` encode command:

```bsh
ffmpeg -ss $(bc -l <<< 1768*1001/24000) -t $(bc -l <<< (1798-1768)*1001/24000) -i input.mkv -c:v libx265 -crf 21 -an -preset slower -x265-params "bframes=6:pools=4" 0.mkv
```

MPV screenshot:

[image]

`ffprobe` output:

```bsh
ffprobe version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin -fno-stack-check' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from '0.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 01:37:09.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 66 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 0.792000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.000
    Chapter #0:1: start 0.792000, end 30.572000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:00.792
    Chapter #0:2: start 30.572000, end 332.207000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:00:30.572
    Chapter #0:3: start 332.207000, end 548.423000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:05:32.207
    Chapter #0:4: start 548.423000, end 842.675000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:09:08.423
    Chapter #0:5: start 842.675000, end 1142.850000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:14:02.675
    Chapter #0:6: start 1142.850000, end 1416.832000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:19:02.850
    Chapter #0:7: start 1416.832000, end 1655.112000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:23:36.832
    Chapter #0:8: start 1655.112000, end 1788.745000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:27:35.112
    Chapter #0:9: start 1788.745000, end 1968.758000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:29:48.745
    Chapter #0:10: start 1968.758000, end 2238.695000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:32:48.758
    Chapter #0:11: start 2238.695000, end 2966.005000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:37:18.695
    Chapter #0:12: start 2966.005000, end 3386.425000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:49:26.005
    Chapter #0:13: start 3386.425000, end 3967.213000
    Metadata:
      title           : 00:56:26.425
    Chapter #0:14: start 3967.213000, end 4405.985000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:06:07.213
    Chapter #0:15: start 4405.985000, end 4863.025000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:13:25.985
    Chapter #0:16: start 4863.025000, end 5359.354000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:21:03.025
    Chapter #0:17: start 5359.354000, end 6086.560000
    Metadata:
      title           : 01:29:19.354
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.54.100 libx265
      DURATION        : 00:01:13.741000000
    Stream #0:1(rus): Subtitle: ass
    Metadata:
      title           : Licence West Video
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.54.100 ssa
      DURATION        : 01:37:09.020000000
```

Edit: update conversion log. The original `-report` log is a monstrous 78 MB text file. I delete the repeated lines in the middle and this is the [result](https://pastebin.com/sKHFZ6jk).

Comment: Share full conversion log.

Comment: @Gyan that would be too long. I think I found a way to get around this: use `-t` as output option, by moving it after `-i`. Can you confirm that this is an abnormal behavior of `ffmpeg`?

Comment: Need to see full log. You can upload it to pastebin or similar. Add -report to your command.

Comment: @Gyan I added the partial log...

Comment: It's due to the subtitles. Add `-sn` to remove those. But output `-t` is also fine.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Could it also because of the chapter markers?

Comment: No, it's related to trimming the subs as per `-t`. I can debug it when I have time.